# How to get a list of the most accessed folders / files in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, file-management

I am about to install an SSD NVME 256 Mb, which is several times faster than my two current raid 0 SSDs.

However, once it has little space, I want to leave only the most accessed files/folders historically.
Least accessed files/folders will be left on the old SSD to save space for the new SSD.

How do I get a list of, for example, the most accessed files/folders in the last week?

Comment: If you have never cleared this file it will have a fairly comprehensive list but not sorted, add the Date Accessed column to help sort>>>C:\Users\Your User Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent

Comment: Thanks, but this shows the `Latest` accessed files, but it would be better to have to `Most` accessed instead.

Comment: You need to add the Date Accessed column, not exactly what you need but you will have to look for the most entries by sorting the different columns.

Comment: I understand, but in practical terms, a file's last access date does not necessarily say that it is a constantly accessed file. I may have several recently accessed files that will appear in the list you proposed, however, that does not mean that it is accessed constantly (which would justify leaving this file on the faster SSD).
Apparently, I'll need an external application that does this work. But I do not know.

Comment: But Date Accessed will show how many times it was accessed, you have to do some homework studying the columns, this has been asked here before and if memory serves me right there is no way to do what you want using windows tools. Let us know if you find an answer using third party software that can sort the data the way you need it.

Comment: It might be more practical to consider *most used folders*. E.G. Windows OS is accessed from boot up, so that's a prime candidate to move, as are the two Program Files folders and user data. Folders with large files such as images, documents, music and video are probably best left on a large HDD.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, of course, but I just wanted to know if there is a more "scientific" way to analyze this. Anyway, thank you all for your ideas.